# Extjs 4.0.7 grid utf8 encoding issue

Tags: extjs, utf-8, extjs4

I have a grid and arrived data (Ext Direct), for example (firebug):

[image]

But in the grid you see:

[image]

If I click double to show full data, in the title of window, this data does not have trouble (come from the record):

[image]

The other columns render datas without problem. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: There is an old thread on the ExtJS forums which may give you some clues - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?89099-Grid-not-showing-UTF-8-encoded-characters.

Comment: Thank you, but it has no solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I also live in a country where we need the accented characters (Slovakia) and I went through all possible encodings and troubles with localization. After all, UTF-8 is the real solvent. Since I use UTF-8 in database, in apache (Ajax) headers and on the HTML on the page I have no problmes.

Therefore, check if somewhere in the route the encoding does not change, check if UTF-8 is really sent from the server, check all headers, etc. The only problem that UTF-8 ceased to be used somewhere on the route.